# How to play an array of songs using streamingkit library

Tags: ios

Has anyone out there ever used this https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit/ package to play remote mp3 files? How can one load an array of music urls and play them one after the other?

Answer (score 2):

Just as document says:

```
STKAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] init];
[audioPlayer queue:@"http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/sample.mp3"];
[audioPlayer queue:@"http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/airplane.aac"];
```

You just need to add url to queue.